# How can I force a div to redraw on a browser resize?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm implementing a piece of css to resize fonts based on window size.

It works seamlessly in Chrome, however the resize only works in Safari on a page refresh.

I believe the root cause of this is that the css uses rem units, which I see Safari has noted issues with.

It feels hacky, but the only solution i can think of is to force a redraw for the div containing the fonts on a page resize. Can anyone recommend a neat piece of js to do this?

Here's the css

Many Thanks

```
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


html {
        height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  font-family: 'source-serif-pro', sans-serif;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  font-family: 'source-serif-pro', serif !important;
}

body {
  text-align:center
}

pre {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: white;
  border: solid 1px #777;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  border: 1px solid #666;
}

td, th {
  padding: 0.25rem .5rem;
  border: 1px solid #666;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}
html {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 10rem) {
  html {
    font-size: calc(0.8rem + 1.2 * ((100vw - 20rem) / 30));   }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 100%) {
  html {
    font-size: 2rem;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; 

  }


}

body {
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

p {
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5 {
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 0.7rem;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 0.5rem;
  line-height: 0.5rem;
  margin-top: calc((1.5rem - 1rem) + 1.5rem);
}

h2 {
  font-size: 0.3rem;
  line-height: 0.5rem;
  margin-top: calc((0.3rem - 0.3rem) + 0.3rem*2);
}

h3 {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  line-height: 1.25rem;
  margin-top: calc((1.5rem - 1.25rem) + 1.5rem*2);
}

h4 {
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1rem;
  margin-top: calc((1.5rem - 1rem) + 1.5rem*2);
}

h5 {
  font-size: 0.2rem;
  line-height: 0.2rem;
  margin-top: calc((1.5rem - 0.875rem) + 1.5rem*2);
}
```

Comment: Hm, why don't you post your CSS here and perhaps someone can help you get it working w/o needing to resort to JS?

Answer (score 1):

You could have an event listener on window resize.

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    ...
};
```

You may wanna try using viewport units.

```
vw, vh 1vw = 1% of viewport width 1vh = 1% of viewport height
```

This will work without using the javascript approach.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function I've found useful for force-repaint in odd cases where it's been necessary, but you may want to post CSS and see if folks can help with a JS-free solution as suggested.

```
function forceRepaint(el) {
  el.style.transform = 'scale(1)';
  requestAnimationFrame(function () {
    el.style.transform = '';
  });
};
```

You'll want to run this inside a debounced window resize handler.